# Using jquery.fs.selecter, select is not getting reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried so many ways to reset the select dropdown but its not getting reset. Following are the way I have tried:-

```
                    .find("select")
                .prop('selectedIndex',0)
                .end();



    $('#duration').prop('selectedIndex', 0);

   $('span.selecter-selected').val(0);
```

Last try I did because span is creating with selecter-selected class. I dont understand what do I do? I think it is creating because I am using jquery.fs.selecter.min.js

Answer (score 3):

I think you're using plugin for select-box like 'chosen' or 'bootstrap select'. Then you've to use appropriate Plugin option to reset the select-box.

You're using jquery fs.selector may be you could use

$(".target").selecter("update");

http://formstone.it/components/selecter

Comment: yes. jquery.fs.selecter is a plugin itself right? I am asking how to reset using this plugin

Comment: Thanks its running :)